# Qual a diferença entre ECMAScript e JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Qual a diferença entre ECMA Script e JavaScript?

Ouço muito o termo ECMAScript, *ES5*, *ES6*, ligado à linguagem JavaScript. Existe semelhança entre esses dois *termos*?

Comment: Ecmascript é a linguagem, e javascript é um dialeto, ou seja, a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Cada navegador implementa o javascript de uma maneira diferente e o papel do ecmascript e padronizar essas implementacoes, para que voce nao precise como antigamente escrever um codigo para alguns navegadores e outro codigo para o internet explorer por exemplo.